# SQL Way to return alternate values if many answers match query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am creating a task order "flat file" style continuous form that is based on a query and have instances when I have two task orders that have multiple matches. Specifically, County, Route, and Post Mile limits can be many-to-one task order (ID). The query currently output something like:

```
| ID | County | Route | BegPM | EndPM |
|101 | HUM    |   254 |  0.00 |   0.4 |
|102 | SOL    |   012 |  26.3 |  26.4 |
|102 | SAC    |   012 |  0.00 |   0.4 |
|103 | ELD    |   050 |  43.6 |  43.7 |
|103 | ELD    |   050 |  36.1 |  36.3 |
|104 | YUB    |   020 |   0.4 |  14.3 |
|104 | SUT    |   099 |  37.0 |  39.2 |
```

I would like task orders with more than one County, Route, or post mile entry to be one result and have "VAR" replace the respective values. Examples:

```
| ID | County | Route | BegPM | EndPM |
|101 | HUM    |   254 |  0.00 |   0.4 |
|102 | VAR    |   012 |   VAR |   VAR |
|103 | ELD    |   050 |   VAR |   VAR |
|104 | VAR    |   VAR |   VAR |   VAR |
```

I've been exploring nested selects and/or IIF statements in the query itself or the criteria, but this one has me stumped as I'm relatively new to SQL. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `iif()` and some type conversion:

```
select id, county, route,
       iif(min(BegPM) = max(BegPM), str(BegPM), "Var") as BegPM,
       iif(min(EndPM) = max(EndPM), str(EndPM), "Var") as EndPM
from t
group by id, county, route
```

Comment: What could I do for the County values as they're text?

Comment: @Calebmcc . . . I don't understand your question.  The `county` is part of the `group by`.  Strings work fine there.

Comment: So the `County` and `Route` values can be VAR as well, not just the `BegPM` and `EndPM`.